# How does task scheduler handle clocks shifting behind or ahead?

Tags: windows, task-scheduler

In the UK, when the clock moves ahead in March, and when the clock moves behind in October then how does the task scheduler handle this?

I know that if UTC is selected then this doesn't matter. However if UTC isn't selected then what is the behaviour?

In march when at 1am it becomes 2am, do the tasks scheduled between 1am to 2am not run?

In October when at 2am it becomes 1am, then do the tasks scheduled between 1am to 2am run twice?

Comment: Clocks do shift

Comment: Well today at 1am the clock immediately changed to 2am

Comment: Clocks shifted this morning at 1am. That is - at 1am the clock shift to 2am. Effectively one hour (1am to 2am) didn't exist. Therefore if a task was scheduled to run at say 01:30, then will it execute or not?

Comment: Your answer is correct only when "Synchronize across all time zones" is enabled. Only then it is relative to UTC. Otherwise it goes by the local time on the machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheduled Jobs during hours of autumn time change](https://serverfault.com/questions/549737/scheduled-jobs-during-hours-of-autumn-time-change)